# if else statement with cplex java

Tags: java, cplex, opl

I have couple of if-else statements. I want to use `cplex` for solving my problem using java and I don't know how to formulate `if-else` in `cplex`. I have this statement:

```
if (stock[i][t] <=Seuil || stock[i][t] <= livraison[i][t] ) 
then ( order[i][t]==Q && stock[i][t+1] == stock[i][t]-livraison[i][t]+order[i][t]);
```

with `stock[i][t]` and `stock[i][t]` : Decision variables
`Seuil`, `livraison[i][t]` and `Q` are known (parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.  I think you are using the OPL language since you used the word "then" in your statement.  If so, then the `if` part of your statement

`if (stock[i][t] <=Seuil || stock[i][t] <= livraison[i][t] )`

is mixing decision variables and parameters/data/known quantities.

If you are trying to model an if-then condition, then you will have to introduce binary variables to represent the different logical conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If you use OPL then you could use logical constraints. Let me give you a small example that works out of your code:

```
int Seuil=5;

range I=1..4;
range T=1..3;
int order[i in I][t in T]=i+t;
int Q=1;

dvar int stock[I][T] in 0..10;
dvar int livraison[I][T] in 0..10;

subject to
{
forall(i in I,t in T:(t+1) in T)
 (stock[i][t] <=Seuil || stock[i][t] <= livraison[i][t] ) 
=> ( order[i][t]==Q && stock[i][t+1] == stock[i][t]-livraison[i][t]+order[i][t]);

}
```